# I am not able to retrieive data from my json file using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have been trying to retrieve data dynamically and not able to find any error
this is the following code
where it contains a class component and i tried doing console.log(currentquestion.question) it is showing me undefined idk what I did wrong in the following code help will be appreciated and would mean a lot as i am trying to learn react
json data

```
[{
        "question": "Who painted the Mona Lisa?",
        "optionA": "Alexander Graham Bell",
        "optionB": "Sir Isaac Newton",
        "optionC": "Leonardo Da Vinci",
        "optionD": "Albert Einstein",
        "answer": "Leonardo Da Vinci"
    }]
```

```
import React, {Fragment } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import questions from '../../questions.json';
import isEmpty from '../../utils/is-empty';


class Play extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            questions,
            currentQuestion: {},
            nextQuestion: {},  
            previousQuestion:{},
            answer: '',
            numberOfQuestion: 0,
            numberofAnswered: 0,
            currentQuestionIndex:0,
            score:0,
            correctAnswers: 0,
            wrongAnswers: 0,
            time: {}
        }
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        const {questions ,currentQuestion,nextQuestion,previousQuestion} = this.state;
        this.displayQuestions(questions,currentQuestion,nextQuestion,previousQuestion);
    }
    displayQuestions = (questions=this.state.questions, currentQuestion,nextQuestion,previousQuestion)=>{
        let { currentQuestionIndex } = this.state;
        if(!isEmpty(this.state.questions)){
            questions = this.state.questions;
            currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
            nextQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex +1];
            previousQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex -1];
            const answer = currentQuestion.answer;
            this.setState =({
                currentQuestion,
                nextQuestion,
                previousQuestion,
                answer
            })
        }
    }
   
    render() {
        const { currentQuestion } = this.state;
        return(
            <Fragment>
                <Helmet><title>Quiz Page</title></Helmet>
                <div className="questions">

                    <div>
                        <p>
                            <span>1 of 15</span>
                            <span className="Lifeline">2:15</span><span className="mdi mdi-clock-outline mdi-25px"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <h5>{currentQuestion.questions}</h5>
                    <div className="options-container">
                        <p className="option">{currentQuestion.optionA}</p>
                        <p className="option">{currentQuestion.optionB}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="options-container">
                        <p className="option">{currentQuestion.optionC}</p>
                        <p className="option">{currentQuestion.optionD}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className = "btn-container">
                        <button>Previous</button>
                        <button>Next</button>
                        <button>Quit</button>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Play;
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any code here that fetches data.  Did you forget to add that?   I don't see any properties being set on `currentQuestion` either.

Comment: @jmargolisvt sorry i forgot to add it its a json data with 6 keys 1 question 4 option and 1 answer key{
        "question": "Who painted the Mona Lisa?",
        "optionA": "Alexander Graham Bell",
        "optionB": "Sir Isaac Newton",
        "optionC": "Leonardo Da Vinci",
        "optionD": "Albert Einstein",
        "answer": "Leonardo Da Vinci"
    },
here is the following example

Comment: You shouldn't add code to comments. ;)  Still not seeing where you fetch that data, though.

Comment: @jmargolisvt i have retrieve the data from the json file you can see on currentQuestionIndex i have initialized its value as 0 and on displayquestion arrow function i have retrieve the data and i am trying to display it under the render function

Comment: @jmargolisvt See `import questions from '../../questions.json';`. The data isn't fetched, it's loaded from file.

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

It seems to me your issue is two-fold:

1. Upon the initial render that `this.state.currentQuestion` is an empty object.
2. Upon subsequent renders that `this.state.currentQuestion.questions` returns undefined because `questions` isn't a property in your JSON data.

## Solution

Since your data is imported and available, initialize your state in the constructor to be what you want it be for the initial render.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    questions,
    currentQuestion: questions[0], // <-- first question object
    nextQuestion: questions[1], // <-- second question object
    previousQuestion: {}, // <-- initially empty
    answer: questions[0].answer, // <-- first question object answer
    numberOfQuestion: 0,
    numberofAnswered: 0,
    currentQuestionIndex: 0,
    score: 0,
    correctAnswers: 0,
    wrongAnswers: 0,
    time: {}
  }
};
```

Access the correct question properties.

```
render() {
  const {
    currentQuestion: {
      question, // <-- question, no questions
      optionA,
      optionB,
      optionC,
      optionD,
    },
  } = this.state;

  return(
    <Fragment>
      <Helmet><title>Quiz Page</title></Helmet>
      <div className="questions">
        <div>
          <p>
            <span>1 of 15</span>
            <span className="Lifeline">2:15</span><span className="mdi mdi-clock-outline mdi-25px"></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <h5>{question}</h5>
        <div className="options-container">
          <p className="option">{optionA}</p>
          <p className="option">{optionB}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="options-container">
          <p className="option">{optionC}</p>
          <p className="option">{optionD}</p>
        </div>

        <div className = "btn-container">
          <button>Previous</button>
          <button>Next</button>
          <button>Quit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```